# Trying to build a core 2.2 User Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a user helper for core 2.2 to make it easier to get the current users information.

I keep getting back an object reference error on this current code

```
private static HtmlHelper _helper;

    public UserHelper(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        _helper = helper;
    }

    public static IIdentity GetUserId()
    {
       var userIdentity = _helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

       return userIdentity;
    }
```

I've searched and most solutions work only in the controller or not at all.   How can i go about getting this to work in a class?

Comment: do you mean [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)?

Comment: Are you talking about a tag helper?

Comment: @vasily.sib yes thats what i'm getting

Comment: @HimanshuPant I might be saying it wrong, but basically i just want to be able to call a class from anywhere and get the current logged in user.  I can do it in a controller, but not a class.

Comment: You cannot inject `HtmlHelper`, and you cannot access it via a static method, if you could.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do here doesn't make sense. First, you cannot inject `HtmlHelper` and second, you cannot rely on an injected value from a static method. The static method is called on the class, not the instance, and the ivar you're attempt to use is only available on an instantiated class instance.

You'd probably be better served by an extension. For example, you can do something like:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IIdentity GetUserId(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var userIdentity = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
@Html.GetUserId()
```

Alternatively, you'd want to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your `UserHelper`, actually *inject* `UserHelper` to get an instance, and then have a non-static `GetUserId` method:

```
public class UserHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public IIdentity GetUserId()
    {
        var userIdentity = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity;

       return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then, in your app's `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<UserHelper>();
```

In places like controller classes, you'd inject `UserHelper` just as anything else. In views, you can use:

```
@inject Namespace.To.UserHelper UserHelper
```